# I don't know how to restore it using the psql command

Tags: postgresql

### psql command

```sh
psql -l db -U postgres -h host -p port < insdb.sql
```

### result

```sh
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 insdb     | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

But, It is not insert data.

How to restore it using the psql command?

Comment: Please share more details. Also, please put your question into the context of programming

Answer (score 1):

Replace `-l` with `-d`.

`-l` just lists databases.

`-d` chooses a DB.

Comment: invalid command \n data,

Is it invalid sql file?

Comment: @gureuso Could be. I have no way to tell.